# How can I structure Firebase Realtime Database Rules to allow sending of "invite" URLs to non-users to allow access to protected user-data structures?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Consider the following protected "room" data structure at `/rooms/room1`:

Data:

```
{
  rooms: {
    room1: {
      content: "hello world",
      authorizedUsers: {
        "UidOfUserA": true,
        "UidOfUserB": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "rooms": {
      "$room": {
        ".read": "data.child('authorizedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".write": "data.child('authorizedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, UserA and UserB can read and write data to `/rooms/room1`. Assume that UserA was able to allow UserB to join because UserA knew UserB's UID.

However, if UserA wants to invite someone who does not yet have an account, by generating a URL and sending it to a friend (not necessarily by email,) this design needs to be expanded on.

How can I structure my rules to allow for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution I can think of would be:

1. allow users to write to their own private sandbox at `/users/$uid/` (so that they can set a value in `/users/$uid/activeInviteToken`)
2. expand on the room rules to also allow users to write to `/rooms/$room/` if their `/users/$uid/activeInviteToken` is found as a child of `/rooms/$room/inviteTokens/`

The workflow would then be:

1. UserA adds a new key to `/rooms/room1/inviteTokens/` (assume it's `/rooms/room1/inviteTokens/inviteToken1`)
2. UserA generates a link with the invite token and the room name and sends it to their friend; e.g. http://example.com/?roomId=room1&inviteToken=inviteToken1
3. after UserC signs up, they write their inviteToken to `/users/UidOfUserC/activeInviteToken` = "inviteToken1"
4. finally, they add `/rooms/room1/authorizedUsers/UidOfUserC`, giving themselves access independent of the inviteToken

While not strictly necessary, completing step 4 allows the user to:

- change their activeInviteToken to something else, so that they can accept an invite to another room, without losing access to room1; and
- expire old inviteTokens

However, this seems overly-complicated, especially the two-step write involving `/users/$uid/activeInviteToken` before adding themselves to `/rooms/room1/authorizedUsers`.